# Round to the second decimal

Tags: matlab

I have a start value that is multiplied at the end of each period with a same number. I put all these values in a matrix A. The values are all displayed with a multiplication by `1.0e+005`. Using `round(A)`, I get integers of six numbers.

I want that all values are rounded to the second decimal. What is the easiest way to do this?

Edit:

This is what I got in my m-file.

```
format short
N = 16;
A = zeros(N,1)
A(1,1) = 425000;
t = 2;

while t ~= N+1
    A(t,1) = 1.02 * A(t-1,1);
    t = t+1;
end

A = round(A*100)/100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
format short
A = rand(5,1);
A' % 0.0462    0.0971    0.8235    0.6948    0.3171
A = round(A*100)/100;
A' % 0.0500    0.1000    0.8200    0.6900    0.3200
```

Comment: Humm this [Matlab syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287407/matlab-syntax-highlighting)...

Comment: It works when I try this in the command window. But when I try to use this in my matlab file (added to the question), I still get values like 1.0e+005 * 4.4217.

Comment: @clubkli Your values _are_ rounded to two decimals, what you see is just a display style. If I run your script, the number with most "decimals" is `1e5*4.6003367` (use `format long` to find this). But this is equal to `100000*4.6003367 = 460033.67`, i.e., two decimals. So make sure to differ between _rounding to some number of decimals_ and _matlab number display style_.

Comment: And how can all these values be displayed as, for example 460033.67?